# take the value of outArgument in activity to another activity

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4

By this :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489442.aspx
but the only diffenet that I make the workflow using a XAML file.

I have a qution: i need to pass the value that I got from the user to another activity.
I tried to make a variable (output for example )and assiged the value, but the another activity see it like empty. may its dead or reset to the default value after the current activity finishs.

I tried to use OutArgument, but it make runtime error at app.run as the following

"The following errors were encountered while processing the workflow tree:
'workflow1': The private implementation of activity '1: workflow1' has the following validation error:   Value for a required activity argument 'Out_arg' was not supplied."
And also didn't see it in the next activity like the first case.

```
[RequiredArgument]
public OutArgument<string> Out_arg { get; set; }

        void OnBookmarkCallback(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, object val)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("im in resume ");
            Console.WriteLine("bookmark1 Name is {0}", (string)val);
            // for the first option that i tried
            output = (string)val;
           //then i tried
            Out_arg.Set(context, (string)val);
```

the xmal file:

  
    
      
        False
        270,2.5
        60,75
        300,77.5 300,107.5 300,129.5
      
    
    
      
        
          
            194.5,129.5
            211,61
            300,190.5 300,220.5 300,279
          
        
        
        
          
            
              
                200,279
                200,22
                300,301 300,331 280,331 280,389.5
              
            
            
            
              
                
                  
                    174.5,389.5
                    211,61
                  
                
                
              
            
          
        
      
    
    _*ReferenceID0*
    _ReferenceID1
    __ReferenceID2

Can u help me?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create variable in you workflow and assign the Out_arg to it?

Comment: yes, I did. I have flowchart contains all my activities. I made a variable in Flowchart scope, and assign the Variable type is bookmark1 (whcih is my class), default value is(new bookmark1()).

Comment: Not quite sure I understand. In your code Out_arg is assigned a string value and now you claim it is of type bookmark1. Doesn't quite add up.

Comment: yes, I did. I have flowchart contains all my activities. I made a variable in Flowchart scope, and assign the Variable type is bookmark1 (whcih is my class), default value is(new bookmark1()). in my 3rd activity(IF) i put (argument1.Out_arg= "yes"), plus in the bookmark1 activity show me the error(value of requird activity argument'Out-arg'was not supplied) even when i used a simple varible inside the bookmark1(output) i wrote(varible1.output= "yes") it didnt see it.

Comment: as u see here: https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=f1fd3ccd21d87c68#!/?cid=f1fd3ccd21d87c68&sc=documents&uc=1&id=F1FD3CCD21D87C68%21188!cid=F1FD3CCD21D87C68&id=F1FD3CCD21D87C68%21351&sc=documents

Comment: and here IF activity: https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=f1fd3ccd21d87c68#!/?cid=f1fd3ccd21d87c68&sc=documents&uc=1&id=F1FD3CCD21D87C68%21188!cid=F1FD3CCD21D87C68&id=F1FD3CCD21D87C68%21352&sc=documents

Comment: I can't really tell a lot from those screenshots. Maybe if you add the xaml to the question.